# find all combinations in an unknown umber of lists

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I'm having some trouble in finding all possible combinations of a certain attribute in a list which is inside a map.

My Map is as follows

```
    Map<Integer, List<Resource>> details = new HashMap<>();
```

and resource class is as follows

```
public class Resource {
private int resourceId;
private int resourceTypeId;
private String code;
private String name;
private double pricePerPackage;
private int companyId;
private String packageName;

//With getters and setters which I haven't copied here
```

}

the key of the map is resourceTypeId, i.e. I have grouped lists of resources with the same resourceTypeId in a list.

Now what I want to do is to get all the possible combinations of pricePerPackage in different lists. the number of lists are unknown.
How can I develop a logic to do so?

EDIT

for example the map may be as follows

List with key 1

[com.eventsia.util.domain.Resource@71dac704, com.eventsia.util.domain.Resource@2d363fb3]

List with key 2

[com.eventsia.util.domain.Resource@7d6f77cc, com.eventsia.util.domain.Resource@5aaa6d82,  com.eventsia.util.domain.Resource@6f75e721]

1 ==> 1, 1,"A", "ABC", 20.0, 3, "Abcd"

1 ==> 2, 1,"B", "BCD", 40.0, 5, "lloo"

2 ==> 3,2,"F" "Foo", 60.0, 3, "Foo"

2 ==> 4,2,"G" "Goo", 50.0, 4, "Goo"

2 ==> 5,2,"B" "Boo", 65.0, 3, "Boo"

I want all totals I can get like

20+60

20+40

20+65

40+60

40+40

40+65

And.. I have an unknown number of lists

This is what I tried but it is wrong, I cant figure out how to correct it

```
        Map<Integer, List<Resource>> details = new HashMap<>(); //say I Have data in it

add(details, 0, 0);
public double add(Map<Integer, List<Resource>> details,int key,double amt){

    for (int key1 : details.keySet()) {
        if(key1==key)
            break;
        List<Resource> list1 = details.get(key1);
        for (Resource resource1 : list1) {
            amt+=resource1.getPricePerPackage();
            add(details, key1,amt);
        }
        System.out.println(amt);
    }

    return amt;
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from iterating all map entries; and then iterating each list to look for those pricePerPackage? And btw: never ever do you represent **real** currency using **floating point** numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow.  Is one "combination[] of pricePerPackage in different lists" formed by choosing the `pricePerPackage` attribute from one member of each of the lists?  If so, is each such combination *ordered* and / or are the elements associated with the map keys?

Comment: In any case, where are you stuck?  How to implement the selection?  How to avoid duplicates?  How to represent the result?

Comment: I want to find the total price of each combination. Say I have 3 lists in the map. Each list belongs to a different resource type. So I want to add the prices from the first list with all the other prices so I can find all the totals.

Comment: @GhostCat I need  to find totals from different lists from different map entries, Not the total from the list of the same Key

Comment: @SachiniWickramaratne This is not possible to keep the duplicate key entries in Map.  1 ==> 1, 1,"A", "ABC", 20.0, 3, "Abcd"
1 ==> 2, 1,"B", "BCD", 40.0, 5, "lloo". The later will replace the first one